# Ferramenta ou site que visualiza porcentagem das linguagens mais utilizadas no seu github

Tags: git, github

tempos atrás, eu encontrei uma ferramenta que mostrava as porcentagens de linguagens usadas por repositório no meu próprio github. Era uma ferramenta ou site web, infelizmente eu vi muito rápido e não deu pra fixar bem qual era, lembro que tinha gráficos também, por isso estou precisando de ajuda pra identificar que site/ferramenta era esse, pois eu gostaria muito de saber a situação do meu github, qual a linguagem que eu mais estou usando, devido a precisar para fazer um trabalho e preciso ter o embasamento do meu github. Obrigado!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

De cabeça consigo lembrar só do [**Wakatime.**](https://wakatime.com)

Com ele você consegue analisar suas **estatísticas** (como você tá falando).

Dá pra usar ele com o **Sublime**, mas atualmente, eu tô no **VS Code** e não sei se tem extensão nele ou alguma coisa compatível. Outro problema é que talvez ele seja trial, depois de um tempo você terá que pagá-lo, caso queira continuar usando.

// Edit: eu havia respondido sua pergunta pensado em outro conceito, acho que o que quer de verdade seria algo como o: [**PowerBI.**](https://powerbi.microsoft.com/pt-br/integrations/github/)